# Can anyone pls explain me why this Transition won't work?

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile, css-transitions

So I have made this mobile navigation and everything is working fine. My menu icon turns in to a X and I can toggle the is-open class with jQuery. But I can't get this simple transition to work and it is driving me crazy. Can anyone please help me out?

```
.mobile-nav
  background: rgba(0,0,0,1)
  display: none
  padding: 20px 0
  position: absolute
  top: 44px
  transform: translateY(-100%)
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out
  width: 100%

@media (max-width: 770px)
  .mobile-nav.is-open
    display: block
    transform: translateY(0%)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know you can not animate an element having `display:none`.

Which is why your animation isn't working. You can find alternative solutions in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3332179/2333214)

Comment: By the time the animation runs it gets display block right? Edit: Even so you are indeed right. It worked but I do find it strange.

Comment: @user3036405 animations occur when a property value changes from one to another. Elements having `display:none` won't be rendered at all, so its like it wasn't there previously so no transition takes place. you can read further [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11056610/2333214)